# how do i include GLFW in CMake with fips?

Tags: c, cmake, game-development, glfw

I have been playing around with some graphics libraries in c and am having a problem while trying to use sokol. The cmake file is (i think) perfectly correct so why would i be recieving the error:fatal  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GLFW/glfw3.h': No such file or directory

glfw location: lib/GLFW/glfw3.h

I am using cmake with the fips build system made by floooh

CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(fps)
add_executable(game src/main.c)
# include the fips main cmake file
get_filename_component(FIPS_ROOT_DIR "../fips" ABSOLUTE)
include("${FIPS_ROOT_DIR}/cmake/fips.cmake")

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

target_include_directories(game PUBLIC /lib/)

# include_directories(src)
fips_setup()

fips_begin_lib(flextgl12)
  fips_src(flextgl12)
fips_end_lib()

if (FIPS_CLANG)
  target_compile_options(flextgl12 PRIVATE -Wno-incompatible-function-pointer-types)
endif()
if (FIPS_CLANG OR FIPS_GCC)
  target_compile_options(flextgl12 PRIVATE -Wno-sign-conversion)
endif()

fips_begin_app(quake cmdline)
  fips_files(src/main.c)
  fips_deps(glfw3)
fips_end_app()
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
#include "sokol/sokol_app.h"

int main() {
  printf("Hello world!");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: where is your GLFW installation located?